# Installing vendors and assetic with Capifony and Syfmony2

Tags: symfony, deployment, assetic, capifony

I am trying to deploy my Symfony2 project to server with capifony but i got this error:

```
      * 2013-06-25 16:22:19 executing `symfony:assets:install'
--> Installing bundle's assets
  * executing "sh -c 'cd /home/user1/releases/20130625142202 && php app/console assets:install web --env=prod --no-debug'"
    servers: ["1xx"]
    [1xx] executing command
 ** [out :: 1xx] 
 ** [out :: 1xx] Warning: require(/home/user1/releases/20130625142202/app/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user1/releases/20130625142202/app/autoload.php on line 14
 ** [out :: 1xx] 
 ** [out :: 1xx] Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/user1/releases/20130625142202/app/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/user1/releases/20130625142202/app/autoload.php on line 14
    command finished in 369ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

here is my output:

- 2013-06-25 16:51:49 executing `symfony:composer:get'
  <ul>
  <li>executing "if [ -e /home/user/releases/20130625145137/composer.phar ]; then echo 'true'; fi"
  servers: ["xx.xxx.xx.xx"]
  [xx.xxx.xx.xx] executing command
  command finished in 488ms
  --> Updating Composer</li>
  <li>executing "sh -c 'cd /home/user/releases/20130625145137 && php composer.phar self-update'"
  servers: ["xx.xxx.xx.xx"]
  [xx.xxx.xx.xx] executing command
  command finished in 377ms
  --> Updating Composer dependencies</li>
  <li>executing "sh -c 'cd /home/user/releases/20130625145137 && php composer.phar update --no-scripts --no-dev --verbose --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-progress'"
  servers: ["xx.xxx.xx.xx"]
  [xx.xxx.xx.xx] executing command
  command finished in 390ms</li>
  <li>2013-06-25 16:51:50 executing`symfony:bootstrap:build'
  --> Building bootstrap file
- executing "if [ -e /home/user/releases/20130625145137/bin/build_bootstrap ]; then echo 'true'; fi"
  servers: ["xx.xxx.xx.xx"]
  [xx.xxx.xx.xx] executing command
  command finished in 336ms
- executing "sh -c 'cd /home/user/releases/20130625145137 && test -f vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php && php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php app || echo 'vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php not found, skipped''"
  servers: ["xx.xxx.xx.xx"]
  [xx.xxx.xx.xx] executing command
  ** [out :: xx.xxx.xx.xx] vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
  command finished in 392ms
- 2013-06-25 16:51:51 executing `symfony:composer:dump_autoload'
  --> Dumping an optimized autoloader</li>
  <li>executing "sh -c 'cd /home/user/releases/20130625145137 && php composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize'"
  servers: ["xx.xxx.xx.xx"]
  [xx.xxx.xx.xx] executing command
  command finished in 417ms</li>
  <li>2013-06-25 16:51:52 executing`symfony:assets:install'
  --> Installing bundle's assets
- executing "sh -c 'cd /home/user/releases/20130625145137 && php app/console assets:install web --env=prod --no-debug'"
  servers: ["xx.xxx.xx.xx"]
  [xx.xxx.xx.xx] executing command
  ** [out :: xx.xxx.xx.xx] 
  ** [out :: xx.xxx.xx.xx] Warning: require(/home/user/releases/20130625145137/app/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/releases/20130625145137/app/autoload.php on line 14
  ** [out :: xx.xxx.xx.xx] 
  ** [out :: xx.xxx.xx.xx] Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/user/releases/20130625145137/app/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/user/releases/20130625145137/app/autoload.php on line 14
  command finished in 417ms
  *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
- executing "rm -rf /home/user/releases/20130625145137; true"
  servers: ["xx.xxx.xx.xx"]
  [xx.xxx.xx.xx] executing command

Comment: provide your deploy.rb please

Comment: please provide your composer.json ... looks like the autoloader isn't dumped and sensio/distribution-bundle isn't being downloaded aswell... `vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php not found, skipped'`

Comment: As I see here, he doesnt do Install or Update with composer in any situation

Comment: hm normally all of the last steps capifony is executing would not be needed ... if you ommit `--no-scripts` when composer is being executed it will already build the bootstrap, dump the assets ... namely what you configure in your composer.json under scripts ... and the optimized autoloader is being dumped there aswell ... no need to execute `composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize` a second time afterwards

Comment: hm searching for `--no-scripts` in the whole capifony repository only returns one hit in the CHANGELOG.md ... Where does that come from during your deployment process? Well it makes sense if you execute the commands through capifony afterwards ... but i think it will most likely be easier to let composer handle the bootstrap-building and stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your **deploy.rb**:

```
set :composer_options, "--no-dev --verbose --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-progress"
```

Make sure `composer update` or `composer install` is executed during the deployment process.

Otherwise **vendor/autoload.php** will not be created and therefore not be available.

Comment: I have this in my deploy.rb


set :use_composer, true
set :update_vendors, true
set :vendors_mode, "install"

Comment: please provide the full output of `cap deploy` - we have to check wether the command is being executed to find out why `vendor/autoload.php` is not being auto-generated